# Can we pass the excel file or .csv file as a table input in karate feature file

Tags: karate

In Karate, we are parameterizing with the below values. Do we have any option of passing the table as external file in karate.

```
And table tablename
     | name | age | id |
     | abc  | 02  | 01 |
     | def  | 03  | 02 |

And def values = { "name": '(#name)', "age": '(#age)', "id" : '(#id)' }
```

Expecting below in karate framework.

```
And table <tablefile.xls>
And def values = { "name": '(#name)', "age": '(#age)', "id" : '(#id)' }
```

Comment: I have marked the answer as correct. @Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate table from .feature file (karate framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030514/how-to-separate-table-from-feature-file-karate-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, the most recommended is to use JSON for maintaining test data.

Please take a look at this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031155/143475

EDIT: Since OP is insisting on Excel, please refer to this other answer where this is explained in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47954946/143475

If I were you I would NOT use Excel and at least use CSV. In my opinion `table` or `set` is far easier to maintain than Excel and you can do it as part of your test `feature` file itself.

Comment: Can i consider that reading Excel / .csv file as "NOT AVAILABLE" in karate. Because we have payload of 50 fields. And it is easy when we have it in excel for filling the test data.

Comment: @PreethiRavi I just edited my answer. So can we consider your capability to write a simple Java utility to read an Excel (or CSV) file into JSON as "NOT AVAILABLE" :)

Comment: May i use "examples" in "Scenario Outline" on the Feature File to pass the xls sheet as file name.                                                         
      Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.xls'}