# Karate DSL: How to pass the the data as A'BC in the scenario outline

Tags: karate

I have sample JSON where all the values for the keys are defined in regex as "#(value)" and the values are dervied from the data table in the feature file. (represented in Example in scenario outline)
eg:- {"key": "#(value)"}

I have one of the record which is like **A'BC** but when I pass this as it is the JS is getting failed with error as : Missing close quote

Example:-

| Value |

| A'BCD |

I tried passing the value with single slash \ in between A and 'BC but it is adding the double slash in the constructed JSON request

JSON constructed :
{"key":  "A\'BCD"}

I need the the JSON to be like
{"key" : "A'BCD"}

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a strategy to "post process" the CSV. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395151/143475 and [Reading csv file converts it to json but it takes every row in it as a string in karate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56578989/143475)

Also be aware of ways to improve dynamic scenario outlines coming in the next version: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905